# $\sigma$-algebra generate by uncountable collection of subsets.

Tags: measure-theory

How would I approach this problem?

> Let $\sigma(F)$ be a $\sigma$-algebra generated by $F$ where $F$ is an
> uncountable collection of subsets of $\Omega$. If $A \in\sigma(F)$,
> then there exists a countable subset $F_c$ of $F$ such that $A \in
>  \sigma(F_c)$.

Comment: How about $F_c = \sigma(A)?$

Comment: Sorry, are you suggesting to prove that?

Comment: @Omnomnomnom But are we sure $A \in F$?

Comment: @user10444 ah, that's what I was missing.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use the "good set principle", i.e. Define

$$
M = \{A \in \sigma(F) \mid \exists \text{ countable } F_A \subset F \text{ such that } A \in \sigma(F_A)\}. 
$$

Show that this is a sigma algebra containing $F$.

Comment: I think showing that $M$ is a sigma-algebra is not difficult. But how to show that $F$ is in $M$?

Comment: @Boby Take a set $A \in F$ then the collection $\{ A \}$ is countable and $A\in \sigma (A)$.

Comment: Could u please elaborate a little more I still dont understand. Sorry

Comment: @Boby What I said shows $F \subset M$ which is what you want.

Comment: Take $F_A = \{A\} \subset F$ for $A \in F$. This shows $A \in M$. As $A \in F$ was arbitrary, $F \subset M$.

Answer (score 0):

Countable compositions of operations, each of which involves countable elements, still involve countable elements. Here you may consider operations such as countable unions, intersections, take complement...